# Create Facebook wall post from embedded application

Tags: c++, facebook, sockets, embedded

I'm working on a project where I want to post a wall message to the users Facebook page but the problem is that the program will run on a very limited system and the only way I have to talk with Facebook is via sockets in C/C++.
Anyone have any code examples of how to do this?
Asking for the username/password is no problem so I will have this but I would also like to be able to do all this without them having to add a application to there Facebook page.

All documentation on Facebook.com is for when you can show a web browser but there must be some way you can do this, right?

/Viktor

Answer (score 0):

sockets <-> Facebook?

the right way to do that is using facebook's REST api or CONNECT. You could try to use [oauth2](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) to authenticate and then make http calls. You can try to use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/). I don't think you can use sockets unless you are inside facebook's layer.

Comment: I can't find a port of curl for my environment, everything I have been able to find is sockets. But are not sockets "the same thing" just on a lower level?

Comment: @Viktor http is just a protocol on top of tcp/ip so you can use stream sockets to implement the http protocol [just like the curl guys did].

Comment: I guess @Viktor wants to use a low level api or something like *read* http://linux.die.net/man/2/read. But I dunno